# VS Code shows wrong function definition when hovering over it

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a function, wrapped with a decorator like so:

```
@acquire_connection
async def add_guild(
    guildId: int,
    channelId: Union[int, None],
    connection: asyncpg.Connection
) -> None:
    """Добавляет гильдию и канал оповещений в таблицу `guilds`"""
    await connection.execute(Query.GUILD_ADD, (guildId, channelId))
```

Here's the `acquire_connection` decorator definition:

```
def acquire_connection(f):
    """Выделяет канал `connection` с базой данных и передаёт его функции"""
    @wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.transaction():
                return await f(*args, **kwargs, connection=conn)
    return wrapper
```

As you can see, even though the `add_guild` coroutine is not static, I do not pass `self` to it when calling it in the decorator, so the function only has 3 actual parameters. When I hover over the function somewhere else in the project though, the **VS Code** shows me this:

[image: Function representation]

He thinks that `guildId` is actually a `self` object and does not include it. It can be fixed if I add `@staticmethod` decorator after the `@acquire_connection`, but it's an extra line of code I don't want, because I have lots of those methods.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I already tried restarting language server multiple times, it does not work*